# Receiving error using ngFor and ngIf in Angulsrjs2 and Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework, ionic2

JoinedArray is an array with some values.
I have to check if the event.listDetails.accessId is present there in the array or not . If accessId is not there in the array then the event-card should not print

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'joined'">
            <event-card *ngIf="event.listDetails.accessId in joinedArray " ></event-card>
    </ion-list>
```

error is:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
>   Property binding ngIfIn not used by any directive on an embedded
>   template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and
>   all directives are listed in the "directives" section. ("e keys and i
>   have to check if it is present in the array or not ..please
>   suggest-->-->
>               [ERROR ->]
>       
>         "): EventListComponent@31:12

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including that *logic* in your view, you could just create a property in the component like this:

```
public showCard: bool;

// In the constructor or somewhere else
//...
this.showCard = joinedArray.indexOf(event.listDetails.accessId) > -1;
// ...
```

And then in the view:

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'joined'">
  <event-card *ngIf="showCard"></event-card>
</ion-list>
```

That way we keep things simple, the view just takes care of showing or hiding things, and the component code decides whether if that should be shown or not.

Please also notice that I've used the `indexOf()` ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)) method to see if the array contains that value.